# Create an array from sync and async values

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

The code below works just fine. Console outputs an array `[1, 2]`.

```
const getAsyncValue = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 1000)
  })
}
const getSyncValue = () => {
  return Rx.Observable.of(2);
}
const observer = (arrayOfValues) => {
  console.log(arrayOfValues);
}
Rx.Observable.of(getPromise(), getSyncValue())
  .concatAll()
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(observer)
```

I'd like to change function `getSyncFunction` to the following (because in a real world application this function might not have a reference to RxJs library):

```
const getSyncValue = () => {
  return 2;
}
```

If I just do that without anything else I get an error:

> You provided '2' where a stream was expected

What other changes to the code do I need? Maybe hint me the operator to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in `getSyncValue()` but in `concatAll()` that works with higher-order Observables. When you pass it just `2` it throws the error. Using `Rx.Observable.of(2)` is correct because it's an Observable that emits a single value `2` which is remitted by `concatAll()`.

I don't know what your code should do but you could do for example:

```
Rx.Observable.of(getPromise(), getSyncValue())
  .map(v => typeof(v) == 'object' ? v : Rx.Observable.of(v))
  .concatAll()
  ...
```

However, I do recommend to rethink this because I guess you could use some easier approach than this.

Comment: I guess you're right. I should rethink this. Anyway, thank you, good sir, for your time and knowledge!